# JavaFX Exception in Application start method file upload

Tags: image, file, javafx

High I've been trying for two days to create a link to a card folder, I'm currently trying to gain add a random card to the interface but I keep on getting an exception I don't understand how my class path is wrong I tried everything any help would be hugely appreciated. I'm at a bit of dead end and I can't find anything that will help with the issue online 
my code is as follows

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
//Imports for components in this application.
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
//Imports for images.
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HighLowJavafx extends Application {
    // Declare labels
    Label lblFirst, lblSecond, lblNext;

    // Declare Radio Buttons

    // radio button 1 with an empty string for its label
    RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton();

    // radio button 2 with an empty string for its label
    RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton();

    Button btnFirst, btnSecond;

    // Declare controls at class scope.
    Label lblStatus;
    MenuBar mBar;

    Image imgRight2;
    ImageView imgViewRight;

    public HighLowJavafx() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {

        // Instantiate components.
        lblFirst = new Label("First Card Dealt:");
        lblSecond = new Label("Second Card dealt:");
        lblNext = new Label("Next Card Will Be:");

        mBar = new MenuBar();
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        // File menu
        Menu mnuFile = new Menu("File");

        // add new game to file menu
        MenuItem newGame = new MenuItem("New Game");
        mnuFile.getItems().add(newGame);

        // add shuffle to file menu
        MenuItem shuffle = new MenuItem("Shuffle");
        mnuFile.getItems().add(shuffle);

        // add exit to file menu
        MenuItem exit = new MenuItem("Exit");
        mnuFile.getItems().add(exit);

        // Add the menu to the menu bar.
        mBar.getMenus().add(mnuFile);

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Create a help menu.
        Menu mnuHelp = new Menu("Help");

        // Add menu items to the help menu.
        MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem("About");
        mnuHelp.getItems().add(aboutItem);

        aboutItem.setOnAction(ae -> showAboutDialog());

        // Add the help menu to the menu bar.
        mBar.getMenus().add(mnuHelp);

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Add image view

        imgViewRight = new ImageView();

        // Handle menu events.
        newGame.setOnAction(ae -> {

        });

    }// init()

    private void showAboutDialog() {

        // Create a new stage and set sizes and title.
        Stage dialog = new Stage();
        dialog.setWidth(250);
        dialog.setHeight(180);
        dialog.setTitle("About");

        // A label for the dialog.
        Label lblAbout = new Label(" Luke Gallagher 2933229 ");

        // An OK button for the dialog.
        Button btnOK = new Button("OK");

        // Handle events (clicks) on the dialog button.
        btnOK.setOnAction(ae -> dialog.close());
        btnOK.setMinWidth(120);

        // Layout for the about dialog.
        VBox vbAbout = new VBox();
        BorderPane dlgBP = new BorderPane();
        dlgBP.setCenter(btnOK);

        // The button.
        BorderPane bpLbl = new BorderPane();
        bpLbl.setCenter(lblAbout);

        // Set the padding.
        vbAbout.setPadding(new Insets(40));
        vbAbout.setSpacing(20);

        // Add components.
        vbAbout.getChildren().add(bpLbl);
        vbAbout.getChildren().add(dlgBP);

        // Create a scene.
        Scene dlgScene = new Scene(vbAbout);

        // Set the scene.
        dialog.setScene(dlgScene);

        // Show the stage.
        dialog.show();

    }// showAboutDialog()

    public int cardNum() {
        int Num = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 52);
        return Num;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage pStage) throws Exception {

        // Set the title.
        pStage.setTitle("Hi-Lo Card Game");

        // Set the width and height.
        // Width and height.
        pStage.setWidth(600);
        pStage.setHeight(400);

        // images
        // fileR = new File("cards/" + cardRight.toString(cardRight)+/".png")
        // imgRight2= new Image("cards/2_of_clubs.png");

        // imgViewRight.setImage(imgRight2);

        // imgRight2= new Image(fileR.toURI().toString());

        // imgViewRight.setImage(imgRight2);

        // Instantiate components.
        lblFirst = new Label("First Card Dealt:");
        lblSecond = new Label("Second Card Dealt:");
        lblNext = new Label("Next Card Will Be:");

        // Start and stop buttons.
        btnFirst = new Button("<- Deal First Card");
        btnSecond = new Button("Deal Second Card ->");

        // Manage button sizes.
        btnFirst.setMaxWidth(130);
        btnSecond.setMaxWidth(130);

        // rb button functionality only one can be selected at once
        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
        RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton("Higher");
        rb1.setToggleGroup(group);
        rb1.setSelected(true);
        RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton("Lower");
        rb2.setToggleGroup(group);

        // Create a layout.
        BorderPane bpMain = new BorderPane();

        // Add components to the layout.

        bpMain.setTop(mBar);

        BorderPane.setAlignment(lblSecond, Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
        BorderPane.setMargin(lblSecond, new Insets(12, 80, 12, 12));
        bpMain.setRight(lblSecond);

        VBox pane1 = new VBox();
        pane1.getChildren().add(lblNext);
        pane1.getChildren().add(rb1);
        pane1.getChildren().add(rb2);
        pane1.getChildren().add(btnFirst);
        pane1.getChildren().add(btnSecond);
        pane1.setSpacing(10);

        BorderPane.setAlignment(pane1, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(pane1, new Insets(40, 12, 12, 120));
        bpMain.setCenter(pane1);

        // images

        // final Image img = new Image("cards/"+cardNum()+".png");
        final ImageView imgView = new ImageView(".cards");

        // vbox2
        VBox pane2 = new VBox();

        pane2.getChildren().add(lblFirst);

        BorderPane.setAlignment(pane2, Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        BorderPane.setMargin(pane2, new Insets(12, 12, 12, 12));
        bpMain.setLeft(pane2);
        // disables max button to keep everything in-line
        pStage.resizableProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);

        // Create a scene.
        Scene s = new Scene(bpMain);

        // Set the scene.
        pStage.setScene(s);

        btnFirst.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                imgView.setImage(new Image("cards/2_of_clubs.png"));

                pane2.getChildren().add(imgView);
                pane2.getChildren().add(lblFirst);

                BorderPane.setAlignment(pane2, Pos.TOP_LEFT);
                BorderPane.setMargin(pane2, new Insets(12, 12, 12, 12));
                bpMain.setLeft(pane2);
            }
        });

        // Show the stage.
        pStage.show();

    }// start()

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Launch the application.
        launch();
    }// main()

}// class
```

the exceptions and errors I'm getting is as follows

```
   Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1118)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:620)
    at javafx.scene.image.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:166)
    at HighLowJavafx.start(HighLowJavafx.java:267)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1110)
    ... 12 more
Exception running application HighLowJavafx
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

Comment: Is this the complete stack trace? (Presumably there is an additional "Caused by..." with the nested exception...?)

Comment: Just added it all now

Comment: So what is the project layout? If you specify the URL for an image without a scheme, according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) it will search on the classpath for a matching resource. So do you have a `cards` folder on the classpath (i.e., in your build folder or jar file) with the corresponding image file inside it?

Comment: Actually, which line is throwing the exception? I assumed it was `imgView.setImage(new Image("cards/2_of_clubs.png"))`, but it looks like it could be `final ImageView imgView = new ImageView(".cards")`. What are you expecting that latter line to do? Can you clarify which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: I think the first one imgView, I read by adding final in front of your image object it overides the exception ... but it doesn't work, I made the ImageView imgView = new ImageView(".cards"); to create a path so I can put it into imgView.setImage(new Image("cards/2_ofclubs.png")), I first tried to make it a random card in my card folder found in the project path but I had no success so I picked the first card 2_of_clubs.png to see if it works.